# Problemas com alocação dinâmica e struct

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, struct, alocação

Pretendo criar uma `struct` onde nela haverá um vetor de `structs`... A forma que pensei em fazer isso foi mais ou menos assim:

```
typedef struct{
    char *teste_str;
    int teste_int;
}TESTE_A;

typedef struct{
    TESTE_A **t;
}TESTE_B;

TESTE_B teste;

int main(void)
{
    teste.t = (TESTE_A**)malloc(3 * sizeof(TESTE_A*));
    teste.t[0]->teste_int = 25;
    printf("%d\n", teste.t[0]->teste_int);
    return 0;
}
```

Mas por que o valor do membro não é alterado e o programa dar erro?

Comment: A primeira coisa que precisa decidir é se vai fazer em C ou C++. O que acontece quando tenta compilar? O código parece confuso. Não sei qual é o objetivo, mas parece ter coisas aí que não deveriam estar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerei que está querendo fazer C. O maior problema é o ponteiro de ponteiro de `t` que não faz sentido. Na verdade os nomes são bem ruins, o código está incompleto e não parece fazer algum sentido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char *teste_str;
    int teste_int;
} TesteA;

typedef struct {
    TesteA *t;
} TesteB;

int main(void) {
    TesteB teste;
    teste.t = malloc(3 * sizeof(TesteA));
    teste.t[0].teste_int = 25;
    printf("%d\n", teste.t[0].teste_int);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/o8ve36). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zmwogtlx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/PointerMember.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu realmente pretendia fazer em C... Desculpe pelo código, é que ainda não tenho nada em mente, apenas queria saber como se fazia isso. Mas compreendi o meu erro, obrigado!

Comment: Agora você pode votar em tudo no site. Veja o [tour].